# Echo "success" after using ftp_put()

Tags: php, ftp, timeout

I have a php script that sends large files via FTP. After the file is sent I'm trying to write to the browser "success". I'm also trying to send a query to the database to record that the file was sent. However, any code that I have that comes after the `ftp_put` does not get executed.

```
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $upload_filename, $filename, FTP_BINARY)) 
{
    echo "File Sent";
    echo $upload_filename." - ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s")." - ".filesize($filename)." bytes<br>" ;
}
else 
{
    echo "Problem while Uploading $filename\n <br/>". $upload_filename ;
}
```

If `ftp_put` is `false` the echo works. But, if the `ftp_put` is a success any code I put there will not run.

The file size I am sending is 7,305kb

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the problem here is that your script is timing out while the file is uploading. Try adding this line before the code above:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `ftp_put()` blocks any further action until the upload is finished.  Try `ftp_nb_put()` (no blocking)  like so:

```
$upload = ftp_nb_put($conn_id, $upload_filename, $filename, FTP_BINARY);

if($upload == FTP_MOREDATA)
{
   echo 'Uploading ' . $upload_filename . ' - ' . date("d/m/Y H:i:s") . ' - ' . filesize($filename) . ' bytes<br />';
   while($upload == FTP_MOREDATA)
   {
       echo '.';  //Output a . to page or do whatever
       $upload = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);
   }
}

//Note: While in the while above, it will either end in FTP_FINISHED or FTP_FAILED
if($upload == FTP_FAILED)
{
    echo "Problem while Uploading $filename\n <br />". $upload_filename;
}
```